# Oracle SQL: If it's not a table or view, what is it?

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for the noobish question, but I'm trying to understand what I'm working with.

I have an Oracle database that I access using Python. The "table" that I usually use doesn't have the data I'm looking for and nobody can tell me where in the database to find it. So, I built a query to list all the tables and views in the database. The "table" I normally use is not listed at all. So if it isn't a table or a view, what is it and how can I find others?

This is an example the SQL query that I use:

```
SELECT MODEL FROM department.node_t WHERE device='Cisco'
```

...which returns all the device models we have that are a Cisco device.

So, what is "department.node_t"? It doesn't show up in the table list nor in the view list:

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables
SELECT view_name FROM all_views
```

Comment: Maybe a materialized view? Try `SELECT mview_name FROM all_mviews;`

Comment: Thanks... That found some for data for me to go through, but still did not show the "table" that I'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try with

```
select * from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'NODE_T';
```

If it returns something, check `OBJECT_TYPE` column which will tell you what it really is, as well as `OWNER` which will tell you who owns it (looks like it could be the `department`).

Also, you could query `DBA_OBJECTS` (if you have a privilege to query it).

Comment: Thank you... I ended up listing all the objects and their values and I determined that the table name is just "node_t". From what you say above, I assume that the owner is "department". I now can determine which other table I can use for my new query.

Comment: You're welcome. Just pay attention to object name letter case; by default, Oracle stores them in uppercase, but you can reference them any way you want (lower/upper/mixed case). However, if you - or someone else - encloses object name into double quotes while creating it (for example, `create table "Node_T" ...`), Oracle will store it exactly like that, and you'll have to reference it using double quotes and using exactly the same case (upper "N", lower "ode", upper "T") - that's why I used UPPER function in my query. Shortly: don't use double quotes when creating Oracle objects.